# What is this MAX17043 LiPo Fuel Gauge connector size?

Tags: batteries, connector, lipo, power-connector

[image]

[image]

I believe this is a type of JST connectors. I bought one piece, and I now need to ..

1. modify my existing lipo battery connector (my connector is smaller)
2. buy another lipo battery with the same connector size

https://www.lithium-polymer-battery.net/select-battery-connector/

I found this website, and I am guessing it's maybe `JST XHP-2`?

Can anybody tell?

Comment: Does the MAX17043 LiPo Fuel Guage have a datasheet?

Comment: right ... https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10617. checked this original product url, and I found a lipo battery compatible with the module.  Checking the data sheet of the battery https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/SPE-00-301120-40mah-en-1.0ver.pdf. I saw it was JST-PHR-2pin.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000007759641.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3ade4c4deh8zJb

I bought one of these OEM versions? (but it looks very much identical).

So I checked Sparkfun's product page.
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10617

There I found a compatible lipo battery, and there was the datasheet.
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/SPE-00-301120-40mah-en-1.0ver.pdf

I ended up spending double the money to buy the cable.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question and its answer has limited value for the community. I must say that you have spent quit a lot of time presenting both.

Comment: @Syed, whatever value kukrt's answer may or may not have, one may rightfully argue the value of your comment.

Comment: Thanks @DavideAndrea I still appreciate the effort that the OP has spent on this page describing related products.